# C# Webmvc AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas() ArgumentException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5.2, argumentexception

I have been working on a WebMVC5 application for some somths now. Suddenly it won't start anymore. The problem has to do with Areas.  I have one area in my project that has always worked. Now when I start debugging I get an ArgumentException.

The Exception occurs on:

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

in Global.asax.cs

The exception message is:

> Value cannot be null or empty.Parameter name: areaName

The exception is not in my code but in the System.Web.Mvc library it seems. When i dive into it its in the CTOR of the AreaRegistration class:

> at System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistrationContext..ctor(String areaName,
>   RouteCollection routes, Object state)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistration.CreateContextAndRegister(RouteCollection
>   routes, Object state)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(RouteCollection
>   routes, IBuildManager buildManager, Object state)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(Object state)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()    at
>   X.Web.Application.WebApiApplication.Application_Start()

I guess my question is, what next?  I tried cleaning the project. I tried reinstalling the nuget packages to the project.

Answer (score 2):

We had exactly the same error/problem. We used Microsofts Fake assemblies for testing our MVC controllers. Somehow, some of those fake assemblies were referenced in the web project as well as in the unit test project. After deleting the referenced fake assemblies from the MVC project everything worked fine - again!

Maybe this helps!

Comment: Maybe this is my problem. I have fakes, but I cant remove them!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error few days ago and I did solve it by:

1. Removing the content in the packages folder.
2. Removing the DLLs inside the bin folder in web project.
3. Build.
4. Run.

Answer (score 0):

Removing content in the folder 'obj' helped me